# How to query GitHub api v4 from client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, graphql, github-api, static-site

I'd like to make a small web app using only client side javascript, that is publicly available on GitHub and hosted via GitHub Pages, that renders information about the different repositories of an organization on GitHub.

Is this possible to do in such a way that:

1. allows me to authenticate with GitHub without compromising a secret key,
2. allows me to query [GitHub's new graphql api](https://developer.github.com/v4/)?

In both cases, the docs seem to suggest that the answer to my questions are "no" and "no":

- for example, the authentication docs emphasize [how to authenticate on the CLI](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/), but I don't find anything on authenticating from a web page via javascript -- is there really no way to do this securely from only the client? Is a server required for this?
- for example, the api v4 docs seem to only mention how to [call the graphql endpoint via cURL](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#communicating-with-graphql) or by using their [GraphQL Explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/using-the-explorer/)

I'm seeking guidance here in the hopes that I'm misreading the docs, and that there really is a way to:

- build a static-site that authenticates with GitHub for the increased query rate limit size,
- and that, when a user visits the page, queries the v4 api and displays the appropriate information about the current status of the various repos of an organization.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without compromising the application key, take a look at [this project](https://github.com/philschatz/gh-board) which host a static site with a "Sign In" functionality where user has to paste a personal token to authenticate the first time

Answer (score 0):

I ignored the documentation and just submitted a POST with a Basic Authorization header.  It seemed to work.  I found the other issue.  Github wants a User-Agent header.  If you are running in a browser that happens automatically, but if you are not you need to add it yourself.  Github documents what should be in it, but apparently does not validate it.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to submit the POST with Basic Authorization header?

Comment: That particular code was test code that is currently deleted.  Also, it was in elm.  Basic Authorization is easy to find.